# Google Analytics: is there any value in adding the URL to a Click Event Category, Action or Label?

Tags: google-analytics

There is a slight disagreement here at our work place. Our Metrics team has us putting the URL into Google Analytics Event `Category`, `Actions` or `Labels`. As far as I can tell, it's redundant because then url appears as `dl` in the `Query String Parameters` when I view the click event in Devtool's Network panel.
Is there any value or reason to add the page URL to Event Category, Label or Action?

Comment: Not really - you can select "page" as second dimension in the reports and that will show the page path, so this would be only useful if you need to full url (host, path, query string and fragment - GA usually does not show the hostname and drops the fragment). However I'm not sure this is a very good question for SO since it's about configuration rather than programming.

Comment: If not Stack Overflow, then where @EikePierstorff ?

Comment: I would suggest webmasters@stackexchange.com.